# Routing subfolder to root URLs

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

In a Razor Pages project I have to override the default UI for ASP.NET Identity. Other that the specific page requirements, I don't want URLs like `/Identity/Account/Whatever` - my pages will be `/login`, `/logout`, etc.

However I still would like to group the authentication pages in a subfolder (not to pollute the top folder), but serve them from "root" URLs.

```
...
Pages
  /Auth
    Login.cshtml           -> /login
    Logout.cshtml          -> /logout
    ResetPassword.cshtml   -> /resetpassword
    ...
  Index.cshtml
  Privacy.cshtml
...
```

Currently to achieve this I have the following code in my Startup.cs

```
services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
  options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Auth/Login", "login");
  options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Auth/Logout", "logout");
  options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Auth/ResetPassword", "resetpassword");
  ...
});

Can this be achieved with some folder convention? Also I don't want to have `/auth/{page}` URLs still working (which is a problem with the current approach).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a custom [Page route action convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.1#page-route-action-conventions).

You can change your code like below.

```
 services.AddRazorPages(options =>
                {
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Auth/Login", "login");
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Auth/Logout", "logout");
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Auth/ResetPassword", "resetpassword");
                    options.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/", model =>
                    {
                        var selectorCount = model.Selectors.Count;
                        for (var i = selectorCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        {
                            var selectorTemplate = model.Selectors[i].AttributeRouteModel.Template;

                            if (selectorTemplate.StartsWith("Auth")) 
                                model.Selectors.RemoveAt(i);
                        }
                    });
                });
```